# Map either numerical values or a character string

Tags: r, shiny, tibble

I'm trying to create a ShinyApp and hoping I could get some pointers.

I'm trying to get a summary table ("Summary score") to represent either i) the minimum value associated with user input for radio buttons (e.g., Id037_crit1 & Id038_crit1) or the text string "NA" if a checkbox is selected (Id039_crit1).

I'm not sure how to change the code such that the summary table shows either the minimum value for the radio buttons or the character string if the checkbox is selected. I'm assuming there's some kind of if-else statement but I can't get it to work.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse) 
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("united"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select",
        label = helpText("Select a critera"),
        choices = list("Criteria_1", "Criteria_2"),
        selected = c("NULL")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Criteria", conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id037_crit1",
            label = "Predictions:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE
          ),
        ),
        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 2", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id038_crit1",
            label = "Hypotheses:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2,
              "Option 3" = 3
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE)
        ),
 
conditionalPanel(h3("Or", align = "left"),
                                     condition =  "input.select == 'Criteria_1'",
                                     awesomeCheckbox(
                                       inputId = "Id039_crit1",
                                       label = "NA",
                                       status = "danger")
        ),

        # User side-pannel selection - criteria 2


        conditionalPanel(h3("Question 1", align = "left"),
          condition = "input.select == 'Criteria_2'",
          prettyRadioButtons(
            inputId = "Id040_crit2",
            label = "Methods:",
            choices = c(
              "Option 1" = 1,
              "Option 2" = 2
            ),
            inline = TRUE,
            status = "danger",
            fill = TRUE)),


      # Second Tab --------------------------------------------------------------


      tabPanel(
        "Summary score",
        DTOutput("summary")
      ),
    ))
  )
)

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  calc_min_val <- function(contains) {
    radios_inputid <- str_subset(names(input), contains)
    map_dbl(radios_inputid, ~ as.numeric(input[[.x]])) %>%
      min()
  }
  
  
  summ <- reactive({
    min_values <- c("crit1$", "crit2$") %>%
      map(calc_min_val)
     
    
    
    tibble(
      Lowest_Criteria = c("Specific hypotheses and prediction are provided?", "Predictions regarding the electromagnetic area of 
interest are sufficient?"),
      value = map(min_values, ~.)
    )
  })
  
  
  output$summary <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(summ())
  })
# Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("DATA", ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasettable(summ()), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
summ <- reactive({
      min_values <- c("crit1$", "crit2$") %>%
        map(calc_min_val)
      if (input$Id039_crit1 & input$select == 'Criteria_1') value = "NA" else value = map(min_values, ~.)
      
      tibble(
        Lowest_Criteria = c("Specific hypotheses and prediction are provided?", "Predictions regarding the electromagnetic area of 
interest are sufficient?"),
        value = value
      )
    })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. Just to clarify, I'm trying to set this up such that if ID039 is selected, "NA" is displayed in the first row of the summary table, whereas if ID037/38 are selected, the minimum value for both of these options is displayed in the first row of the summary table. So the value for Criteria 1 should either show as a minimum numerical value associated with ID037/38, or "NA" if the ID039 checkbox is selected. There was anthat there was an error in my original code which would have caused confusion - I have edited to correct this.

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you! This is super close! Is there some kind of if/else I can use to change it so that "NA" is shown only for Criteria 1, rather than for all criteria?

Comment: You can add the condition `input$select == 'Criteria_1'` to it, as shown above.